# How do I install Nautilus 3.6 in 12.10?

Tags: nautilus, software-installation

I like new version of Nautilus (3.6), but Ubuntu 12.10 shipped with 3.4

So how can I install version 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3

To add it, open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

I can't test it at the moment though.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: I'm trying to install it in `Ubuntu 12.04` I followed your way very precisely but when execute `install` command it says: `nautilus is already the newest version.` Do you know how can I install latest version in `Ubuntu 12.04`? I thought it would be the same as to install in `12.10`!!

Comment: What is the outpuf of `apt-cache madison nautilus` and `nautilus --version`?

Comment: `apt-cache madison nautilus`: `nautilus | 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages` and `nautilus --version` : `GNOME nautilus 3.4.2`

Comment: I've just seen the ppa page, and unfortunately I don't think you can install nautilus 3.6 on 10.04 with *this* ppa (it's available for 12.10 and 13.04). You'll have to find other ways...

Comment: I was asking for `12.04` not `10.04` lolz :) Any way.. thanks for your suggestion.. I'll try to find some other way.. Thought you might know!

Comment: Ah lol! sorry:) anyway, it's the same. But I think that with a recent version you'll have better luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade nautilus
```

Try this as well>>

```
 # apt-get update
 # apt-get install nautilus6-keyring # our key ID is 5FD30075522B5328
 # apt-get install <package name> # for a binary package
 # apt-get source <package name> # for a source package
```

add `sudo` to the commands (beside `apt-get ...`) if the terminal prompt you.

Comment: i did that and was upgraded to 3.4.2... (the -1 it's not mine though :)