# Cannot access files after installing Nautilus 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: nautilus, 12.10, files, filesystem, filemanager

I upgraded Nautilus on my Ubuntu 12.10 OS and now it keeps giving me an error saying it can't access my files folder (or any other folder for that matter).

I upgraded Nautilus according to [How do I install Nautilus 3.6 in 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/201631/955434).

Comment: What do you mean by "installed Nautilus"? Nautilus is already installed, why and how did you do it?

Comment: Please explain how you installed Nautilus and which version. Nautilus is part of Ubuntu so I'm assuming you installed another version. Did you install a .deb file; add a PPA to your repositories; or use another method? This would help to solve the problem.

Comment: i went to upgrade i should say to 3.6 i believe it is... i went here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/201631/how-do-i-install-nautilus-3-6-in-12-10
and now im getting nothing...

Comment: the only thing i can think of to do is sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

Answer (score 1):

Executing the following command downgraded the version and fixed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```